# Trying to set JAVA_HOME in a docker image, don't know why its not working

Tags: docker

I'm a linux scripting novice so go easy please.

I am trying to build a docker image that includes jdk 1.8.0 and has a variable `JAVA_HOME` that points to the location of the jdk.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos
RUN yum install -y wget java-1.8.0-openjdk zip unzip
RUN echo "JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")" | tee -a /etc/profile
RUN source /etc/profile
RUN echo $JAVA_HOME
```

I'm echoing `$JAVA_HOME` just to check that it does get set but here's the output when I build the image:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  50.18kB
Step 1/5 : FROM centos
 ---> 49f7960eb7e4
Step 2/5 : RUN yum install -y wget java-1.8.0-openjdk zip unzip
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 98745c0d3d08
Step 3/5 : RUN echo "JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")" | tee -a /etc/profile
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9e3244072966
Step 4/5 : RUN source /etc/profile
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 99809c08f2e3
Step 5/5 : RUN echo $JAVA_HOME
 ---> Running in c15274d8429f

Removing intermediate container c15274d8429f
 ---> a561301e0546
Successfully built a561301e0546
```

I'm sure there's a simple reason why this isn't working but I can't figure it out.

By the way, I'm doing this because I want to install maven as per these instructions: https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-apache-maven-3-5-on-centos-7 .

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Can you just figure out where it was installed and set JAVA_HOME to that? Instead of doing all the fancy readlink,sed,tee?

Comment: Maybe, but as I'm copying from the aforementioned link I'd like to understand why this isn't working, if nothing else as a learning exercise for myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can echo it if you run it part of the same RUN command:

```
FROM centos
RUN yum install -y wget java-1.8.0-openjdk zip unzip
RUN echo "JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")" | tee -a /etc/profile && source /etc/profile && echo $JAVA_HOME
```